# QtCharts axisX() deprecated

Tags: qt

My code uses QtCharts.

this has - even in the latest docs - the method `axisX()`
I use this for

```
chart->axisX()->setRange(0, data.size());
chart->axisY()->setRange(0, max);
```

However with Qt 5.12 I get this message

> warning: 'QtCharts::QAbstractAxis* QtCharts::QChart::axisY(QtCharts::QAbstractSeries*) const' is deprecated

How am I supposed to replace the code with something not deprecated?

Answer (score 11):

Indeed, the mentioned functions are marked as deprecated in the Qt source code:

```
Q_DECL_DEPRECATED QAbstractAxis *axisX(QAbstractSeries *series = nullptr) const;
Q_DECL_DEPRECATED QAbstractAxis *axisY(QAbstractSeries *series = nullptr) const;
```

I think you have to use the following function instead:

```
QList<QAbstractAxis*> axes(Qt::Orientations orientation = Qt::Horizontal|Qt::Vertical,
                           QAbstractSeries *series = nullptr) const;
```

I.e.

```
auto xAxis = chart->axes(Qt::Horizontal);
auto yAxis = chart->axes(Qt::Vertical);
[..]
```

Comment: Ok. That gives me a list (QList) instead of one value. This works, but is a lot less readable: `chart->axes(Qt::Horizontal).back()->setRange(0, data.size())`

Comment: Well, and you don't get warnings about using deprecated API anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You could also write

```
chart->axes(Qt::Horizontal).first()->setRange(minX, maxX);
chart->axes(Qt::Vertical).first()->setRange(minY, maxY);
```

Instead of:

```
chart->axisX()->setRange(0, data.size());
chart->axisY()->setRange(0, max);
```